# How to save stdin data into class/object [JAVA]

Tags: java, class, object, java.util.scanner, eof

I want to use a Class to hold user inputs. For example `"example_name"`;`"example_value"`;`"example_city"` is the form of the input and I want to make objects from an input stream of theese three inputs line by line from a file. So whenever I enter Adam;27; London it should be saved into an `Object(Adam,27,London)` and ask for the next input.
Thank you for your help, I know this might be a stupid question but I'm new to OO programming and I have a C background and don't want to use two dimensional arrays.

Comment: So what do you have problems with specifically? Do you know how to create the class and instanciate the object? Reading and parsing the input stream? Please show in code what you have tried. Your question is too broad. Please edit it and make it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this problem into 3 section. First, we will have to design the `class`. Second, we will take the user input and create an `object` of that class until the user press n(no). Third, we will display the user information. Here I have used a `LinkedList` data structure for storing the inputs.

Section 1:

```
class example{

   String example_name; 
    int example_value;
    String example_city;
    example(String name,int value,String city)
    {
        this.example_name = name;
        this.example_value = value;
        this.example_city = city;
    }
}
```

section 2:

```
 LinkedList<example> ob = new LinkedList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Press y to Continue n to Exit");
        char i = input.next().charAt(0);
        while(i!='n')
        {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter name");
            String name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter value");
            int value = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Enter city");
            String city = input.nextLine();
            ob.addLast(new example(name,value,city));
            System.out.println("Press y to Continue n to Exit");
             i = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
```

Section 3:

```
 for(example x:ob)
             System.out.println(x.example_name + " " + x.example_value + " "+x.example_city);
```